# Как возвращение блока в исходное состояние сделать плавным? Без js

Tags: html, css, анимация

Не могу понять как возвращение блока в исходное состояние сделать плавным. Как сделать при помощи html и css, без js.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #aaa;
}

.button.one {
  margin: 0 30%;
}

.button.two {
  margin: 0 50%;
}

.button.tree {
  margin: 0 70%;
}

.block.one {
  margin: 0 30%;
}

.block.two {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.block.tree {
  margin-left: 70%;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 23%;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.spanBlock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 46%;
}


/* Connecting animation*/

.button.one:hover+.block.one {
  animation: one 2s forwards;
}

input:checked+.block.two {
  animation: two 2s forwards;
}

.button.tree:active+.block.tree {
  animation: tree 2s forwards;
}


/* End сonnecting animation*/


/* Animation button*/

.button.one:hover {
  background: #bbb;
  transition: 1s;
}

input:checked+div+div {
  background: #bbb;
  transition: 1s;
}

.button.tree:active {
  background: #bbb;
  transition: 1s;
}


/* End animation button*/

@keyframes one {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(150px) rotate(45deg);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes two {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(200px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes tree {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button one"><span>Hover me</span></div>
<div class="block one"><span class="spanBlock">1</span></div>

<input id="ch" type="checkbox">
<div class="block two"><span class="spanBlock">2</span></div>
<div class="button two">
  <label for="ch">
            <span>Click me</span>
          </label>
</div>

<div class="button tree"><span>Hold me</span></div>
<div class="block tree"><span class="spanBlock">3</span></div>
```

Comment: .button.one + .block.one {
  animation: one_h 2s forwards;
}  @keyframes one_h {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(150px) rotate(45deg);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
  }
}  Сделайте тоже самое в обратном порядке

Comment: Почему бы просто не сделать на :hover ?

Comment: `transition` обычно задается не на активный элемент, а на обычный, чтобы плавность работала в обоих направлениях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант отказаться от анимации в пользу переходов

PS в анимации нужно добавить **transition** в оригинальный блок .block.one {**transition: all 2s;**} 
**!** но если анимация не доиграет до конца возврат будет скачком.

PSS в анимации нужно создать обратную анимацию.. и привязать её без ховера. Но в простом варианте она будет проигрываться при старте страницы.. что не есть гуд.

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  color: #aaa;
}

.button.one {
  margin: 0 30%;
}

.button.two {
  margin: 0 50%;
}

.button.tree {
  margin: 0 70%;
}

.block.one {
  margin: 0 30%;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.block.two {
  margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.block.tree {
  margin-left: 70%;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: all 2s;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 23%;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.spanBlock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 46%;
}


/* Connecting animation*/

.button.one:hover+.block.one {
/*  animation: one 2s forwards;*/
    transform: translateY(150px) rotate(45deg);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
}

input:checked+.block.two {
/*  animation: two 2s forwards;*/
    transform: translateY(200px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
}

.button.tree:active+.block.tree {
/*  animation: tree 2s forwards;*/
    transform: translateX(400px);
}


/* End сonnecting animation*/


/* Animation button*/

.button.one:hover {
  background: #bbb;
  transition: 1s;
}

input:checked+div+div {
  background: #bbb;
  transition: 1s;
}

.button.tree:active {
  background: #bbb;
  transition: 1s;
}


/* End animation button*/
/*
@keyframes one {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(150px) rotate(45deg);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes two {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: #aaa;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(200px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
  }
}

@keyframes tree {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
}*/
```

```html
<div class="button one"><span>Hover me</span></div>
<div class="block one"><span class="spanBlock">1</span></div>

<input id="ch" type="checkbox">
<div class="block two"><span class="spanBlock">2</span></div>
<div class="button two">
  <label for="ch">
            <span>Click me</span>
          </label>
</div>

<div class="button tree"><span>Hold me</span></div>
<div class="block tree"><span class="spanBlock">3</span></div>
```